# Reading a big text document and filling up a JProgressBar as it's being read

Tags: java, swing, filereader, jprogressbar

I'm trying to figure out how to make a JProgressBar fill up as a file is being read. More specifically I need to read in 2 files and fill 2 JProgressBars, and then stop after one of the files has been read.

I am having trouble understanding how to make that work with a file. With two threads I would just put a `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`loop and `setValue(i)` to get the current progress. But with files I don't know how to set the progress. Maybe get the size of the file and try something with that? I am really not sure and was hoping someone could throw and idea or two my way.

Thank you!

Update for future readers:

I managed to solve it by using a `file.length()` which returned the size of the file in bytes, then setting the bar to go from 0 to that size instead of the regular 100, and then using

`for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)`

To get the bar loading like it should.

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Comment: Hint use [ProgressMonitorInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html)

Comment: @userunknown Thanks for the replies! I ended up just reading the size of the file in Bytes and setting the JProgressBar(0, fileSizeInBytes) and doing the same for loop but with the total size instead of the fixed number!

Comment: reading byte by byte? it's not a good idea.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Why? Everything seems to be working fine with that, is there a better way?

Comment: you should wait for proper answers, or might take a look at what @Abhi suggested(i do not know that api). it's not as bad as my first intuition, thanks to operating system's preloading mechanism, but if your file is big, your tight loop is not doing too much work on loading, and you update your progress bar for too many times, which subsequently might trigger unnecessary UI updates.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Thanks for the tip! I'm still new to this kind of thing so something like that didn't cross my mind, but I appreciate you pointing that out for me!

Answer (score 2):

Example usage of ProgressMonitorInputStream. It automatically display simple dialog with progressbar if reading from InputStream takes longer - you can adjust that time by using: setMillisToPopup, setMillisToDecideToPopup.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(640, 480);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        String filename = "Path to your filename"; // replace with real filename
        File file = new File(filename);

        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
             ProgressMonitorInputStream progressInputStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(mainFrame, "Reading file: " + filename, inputStream)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10];   // Make this number bigger - 10240 bytes for example. 10 is there to show how that dialog looks like

            long totalReaded = 0;
            long totalSize = file.length();
            int readed = 0;

            while((readed = progressInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                totalReaded += readed;
                progressInputStream.getProgressMonitor().setNote(String.format("%d / %d kB", totalReaded / 1024, totalSize / 1024));

             // Do something with data in buffer
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
```